# How can I get Pandas to create sumsum in new columns by starting at the next row down?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I'm trying to create a "slide" of the cumulative sum of an amount for various scenarios, and start the cumsum from the next row down each time.

I'm trying to get something similar to:

```
Start   Price   Amt.    1       2       3       4       5
4105    1.6     1234                    
4105    1.65    1183    3986.7              
4105    1.74    235     3963.2  4081.5          
4105    1.5     1848    3778.4  3896.7  3920.2      
4105    1.45    3183    3460.1  3578.4  3601.9  3786.7  
4105    1.47    7295    2730.6  2848.9  2872.4  3057.2  3375.5
4105    1.31    4384    2292.2  2410.5  2434    2618.8  2937.1
4105    1.41    734     2218.8  2337.1  2360.6  2545.4  2863.7
4105    1.4     2773    1941.5  2059.8  2083.3  2268.1  2586.4
4105    1.4     4429    1498.6  1616.9  1640.4  1825.2  2143.5
4105    1.4     396     1459    1577.3  1600.8  1785.6  2103.9
4105    1.38    461     1412.9  1531.2  1554.7  1739.5  2057.8
4105    1.38    186     1394.3  1512.6  1536.1  1720.9  2039.2
4105    1.38    368     1357.5  1475.8  1499.3  1684.1  2002.4
4105    1.47    362     1321.3  1439.6  1463.1  1647.9  1966.2
4105    1.43    601     1261.2  1379.5  1403    1587.8  1906.1
4105    1.4292  307     1230.5  1348.8  1372.3  1557.1  1875.4
4105    1.368   132     1217.3  1335.6  1359.1  1543.9  1862.2
4105    1.31    1891    1028.2  1146.5  1170    1354.8  1673.1
4105    1.31    335     994.7   1113    1136.5  1321.3  1639.6
4105    1.34    265     968.2   1086.5  1110    1294.8  1613.1
4105    1.22    701     898.1   1016.4  1039.9  1224.7  1543
4105    1.2     832     814.9   933.2   956.7   1141.5  1459.8
4105    1.17    2759    539     657.3   680.8   865.6   1183.9
4105    1.1799  7       538.3   656.6   680.1   864.9   1183.2
4105    1.2     2       538.1   656.4   679.9   864.7   1183
4105    1.19    100     528.1   646.4   669.9   854.7   1173
4105    1.08    2561    272     390.3   413.8   598.6   916.9
4105    1.1     3063    0       84      107.5   292.3   610.6
4105    1.05    660             18      41.5    226.3   544.6
4105    1.11    947             0       0       131.6   449.9
4105    1.3     4381                            0       11.8
4105    1       103                                     1.5
4105    1.0799  1                                       1.4
4105    1.0068  124                                     0
```

The Start, Price and Amt. values are in the dataframe. The first value (3986.7) is 10% of the Amt. on that day (118.3), subtracted from the Start value (constant). The next value is the cumsum of 10% of the the first amount plus the second amount (118.3+23.5) subtracted from 4105. In the second column, we start with the same 4105, but start by subtracting 23.5, etc. The rows for each of these "slides" should be empty, or NaN.

The code below gets me close (the two lines at the end replace negative numbers with 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("datafile.csv")
length = len(df)
begPos = df.Position
df['sub_value'] = df.Volume*.1
for x in range(10):
    df['slide_' +str(x)] = begPos.shift(1-x) - df.sub_value.shift(-x).cumsum()


numb = df._get_numeric_data()
numb[numb < 0] = 0
```

This will give me the correct values, but start them all in the top row.

I've tried playing with the shift values (I have a whole matrix on every permutation x, -x, x-1, X+1, etc. for every combination), and just can not get this to work.

There are still a few more parts to this program after I solve this, but I hope those will be easy in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column for the 10% values, then use it with cumsum() in a loop.
Finally, you can replace NaNs with "", and drop the unneeded column.

```
df["10pcnt"]=df["Amt."].div(10)

    Start   Price  Amt.  10pcnt
0    4105  1.6000  1234   123.4
1    4105  1.6500  1183   118.3
2    4105  1.7400   235    23.5
3    4105  1.5000  1848   184.8
4    4105  1.4500  3183   318.3
5    4105  1.4700  7295   729.5
6    4105  1.3100  4384   438.4
7    4105  1.4100   734    73.4
8    4105  1.4000  2773   277.3
9    4105  1.4000  4429   442.9
10   4105  1.4000   396    39.6
11   4105  1.3800   461    46.1
...

for i in range(1,len(df)): 
  df[i]= df.Start.sub(df.loc[i:,"10pcnt"].cumsum()) 
  df[i]= df[i].where(df[i]>=0,np.nan) 


    Start   Price  Amt.  10pcnt       1       2       3  ...
0    4105  1.6000  1234   123.4     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...
1    4105  1.6500  1183   118.3  3986.7     NaN     NaN  ...
2    4105  1.7400   235    23.5  3963.2  4081.5     NaN  ...
3    4105  1.5000  1848   184.8  3778.4  3896.7  3920.2  ...
4    4105  1.4500  3183   318.3  3460.1  3578.4  3601.9  ...
5    4105  1.4700  7295   729.5  2730.6  2848.9  2872.4  ...
6    4105  1.3100  4384   438.4  2292.2  2410.5  2434.0  ...
7    4105  1.4100   734    73.4  2218.8  2337.1  2360.6  ...
8    4105  1.4000  2773   277.3  1941.5  2059.8  2083.3  ...
9    4105  1.4000  4429   442.9  1498.6  1616.9  1640.4  ...
10   4105  1.4000   396    39.6  1459.0  1577.3  1600.8  ...
11   4105  1.3800   461    46.1  1412.9  1531.2  1554.7

df.drop(columns="10pcnt")
df.replace(np.nan,"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. however, I'm not able to get the .Start. command to work. I've tried in a few different environments, and all error out.